# What is the highest UIRouter version compatible with Angular 6?

Tags: angular, angular6

**Context**: My team and I are currently finishing the migration of our app from AngularJS to Angular 6 (at last!!). 
Since we're already using UIRouter's implementation for angular-hybrid, we don't want to switch to Angular routing just yet.
Now, to the heart of the problem: I cannot find for the life of me, which version of @uirouter/angular is compatible with Angular 6!
According to our current `package-lock.json`, we can be 100% sure that `@uirouter v2.0.1` is compatible with our app, along with `@uirouter/core v5.0.1`, but I feel like it is our hybrid implementation that held us back from having, say, `@uirouter v5.0.1` instead.
So, instead of having to brute force the potential compatibility issues, I would like to have access to some sort of reference table or developer knowledge about `@uirouter/angular` compatibility with Angular 6.

Thanks!

MA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dum dum me just found this: https://github.com/ui-router/angular/releases 
For anybody wondering which @uirouter/angular version is compatible with Angular 6, along with dependencies: 
`@uirouter/angular v5.0.0`
`@uirouter/core v6.0.1` 
`@uirouter/rx v0.6.0`